# ¿como mostrar únicamente el contenido de /app en la vista de los archivos del proyecto de android studio?

Tags: android-studio

[image: Explorador de archivos de androidStudio]

**Quiero que en el explorador de archivos solo se muestre lo que hay dentro de la carpeta "app".**

Llevo ya un par de meses usando `Android Studio` y he visto en videos que tienen el explorador de esa forma, he buscado en google y en videos de android estudio desde cero como el de píldoras informáticas y la geekipedia de Ernesto, Pero en ningún lado hallo la solución.

Comment: Dale click a 'Android' (lo que haz encerrado) y si no me equivoco ahi te sale la opcion.

Comment: Hola gracias por comentar, acabo de intentar lo que me indicaste y con el click izquierdo aparecen diferentes opciones pero ninguna es la que deseo, y con el click derecho, probe algunas de sus opciones, pero ninguna dio el resultado.

Comment: Te refieres a la "vista de archivos del proyecto", el "explorador de archivos" es esto http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStudioTooling/article.html#device-file-explorer   @ErickLesserDiaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar únicamente el directorio `/app` cambia el tipo de visualización de tu proyecto de "Android" a [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Esta es la forma de realizarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma únicamente se mostrará el contenido de `/app`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal puedes cambiar la vista del como se visualizan tus proyectos, solo selecciona en donde dice "Android" (el cual tienes encerrado en rojo) y se te desplegaran opciones, puedes elegir "production" o "Project Souces Files" para que cambie la vista.

Espero te funcione y sea lo que buscas.
-Saludos